# Update variable when data in databases has changed

Tags: c#, mysql

Here I have three variables, and the variables are filled by the data from the database and displays it to the screen using the label. 
But when I change the data in the database, the variables are not automatically changed. 
What would I try to do is create a variable to change automatically when the data in the database changes. 
But I do not know how to do because I'm new at this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace vendingInterface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public MySqlConnection conn;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        private string produk11;
        private string produk22;
        private string produk33;


        public Form1()
        {
            bacadatabase();
            InitializeComponent();
            info();

        }
```

I display it using the label

```
        private void info()
        {
            lbl_produk1.Text = "Jumlah Produk 1 = " + produk11 + " Buah";
            lbl_produk2.Text = "Jumlah Produk 2 = " + produk22 + " Buah";
            lbl_produk3.Text = "Jumlah Produk 3 = " + produk33 + " Buah";
        }
```

I took the data in the database

```
        public void bacadatabase()
        {
            string sql = "select *from vanding_machine";
            server = "localhost";
            database = "db_s2u";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";

            string connString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + " DATABASE=" + database + ";" + " UID=" + uid + ";" + " PASSWORD=" + password + ";";  //conek SQL
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);


            conn.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Koneksi Berhasil");

            //command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

            //reader
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                produk11 = dataReader["produk1"].ToString();
                produk22 = dataReader["produk2"].ToString();
                produk33 = dataReader["produk3"].ToString();
            }


            dataReader.Close();
            conn.Close();

        }
```

When I click the button the data will be entered into the database and variables in the show will be updated automatically

```
        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            server = "localhost";
            database = "db_s2u";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";

            string connString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + " DATABASE=" + database + ";" + " UID=" + uid + ";" + " PASSWORD=" + password + ";";  //conek SQL
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);


            conn.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Koneksi Berhasil");


            string sql = "update vanding_machine set produk1 = @produk111;";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@produk111", tb_produk1.Text));

            //close data reader
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            conn.Close();

        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so you read some values at some point, but you have to go check if those values change, SQL does not notify on change

Comment: @BugFinder then how can I know if the data in the database change if sql not give notice. Do you have a solution? because I do not have a solution

Comment: are you inserting from your form to the database, do you check your database to ensure what you have inserted is there

Comment: yes I inserting from my form. Yes I also check it @sea50

Comment: load your database data to a `dataGridView` then use the `cellClick` event to display your info to a form.....long short but will work :)

Comment: @FekiPangestuWijaya try to put your `info()` under one of the buttons and click it every time you have updated

Comment: @sea50 I want to make it update without click any button

Comment: the problem is under the `intializeComponent()` that runs once only when the form is loaded, to dynamically update, i suggest, load your data to a `datagridview` then use the `cellclick` event for the datagridview to view on some kind of "master detail form",alternatively load to a `dataTable` then read from that `dataTable` there you could display on your labels but your form needs to be reloaded to view changes/updates made otherwise that won't just happen

Comment: @sea50 I had it done, by creating a timer and check it periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create timer to check whether was data changed or not in application. The database will not point up the application about any change

Comment: I do not know how to create it. Can you explain it clearly to me @Erik Šťastný

Comment: I have tried it and it work properly. thank you @Erik Šťastný